# How do I make the container div be as wide as the h1 element in it

Tags: html, css, width

I need the container div to be as wide as the h1 element and to change with font size changes. Currently everything is as wide as the page.

This is the code:

```
<div id="container">
<h1>ABCDEFGH</h1>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="main-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Credits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>      
</nav>
</div>
```

How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the display of the container div to inline-block

```
<div id="container" style="display:inline-block">
```

You can alternatively add this line to your CSS file

```
#container { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: I fiddled around with `display: inline-block` but for some reason it didn't work when I applied it. Thank you, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/LjrEB

```
#container {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="container">
    <h1>ABCDEFGH</h1>
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <div class="main-menu-container">
                <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Credits</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test item 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>      
    </nav>
    </div>

    <style>
    #container{
    display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>
```

Hope i helped..

Answer (score 0):

You should use ***display:inline-block;*** on the container:

http://jsfiddle.net/gtJMD/

```
<div id="container" style="background:red;display:inline-block;">
<h1>ABCDEFGH</h1>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="main-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Credits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>      
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your CSS should have something like this

```
#container {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

also not that if you close your `<div>` outside `<nav>` and your `<nav>` is positioned relative and has a float property the width of `div#container` will span both the widths of the `<h1>` and `<nav>` element.